# Wait till next page fully loads

Tags: javascript, html, css, preload, preloader

I have page 1 and page 2, A button in page 1 takes a user to page 2. I want a javascript to wait till page 2 has fully loaded before displaying it when the user clicked the button in page one, In between I need to put loading gif, so that visitor will know that something is loading.
How can I achieve that using pure javascript?

No jQuery please.

**EDIT:**
The javascript has to be pasted in page one, so that the button would be the trigger, do note that we can't load page 2 in div as some might suggest to load page two in div, then read if page two is fully loaded then display div.

Comment: Look into [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) and [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) events

Comment: DOMContentLoaded is only to be used when not waiting for css and other scripts, but load event would have to be used in second page I guess, or is there a way to use the load event in page one? as I want the button in page one to be the trigger.

Comment: In that case I think you'll have to resort to XHR requests.

Comment: @HusamIbrahim how can I achieve it using XHR request as you pointed out, I'm really a novice.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646805/display-loading-image-while-ajax-fetches-file-content) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

`window.onload` 
might be what you’re looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    //Your code
});
```

Comment: Can I use this in page 1, so that it would detect the loading status of page two? remember that the I want the loading screen when visitor clicks the button on page one.